# Intermittent success with AssumeRole from Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I am running the STS `AssumeRole` operation from inside a Lambda function and experiencing weird behaviour. My Lambda function runs as a dedicated Role, call it `LambdaRole`, and I'm trying to assume a second role (call is `S3Role`) in order to get credentials for S3 access that I can pass to another system. This other system doesn't have an IAM role attached and I'd rather not generate static keys for that system.

The operation *sometimes* succeeds upon first deploying my Lambda function, and continues to work for a while, but eventually stops working. The 'stopped working' is simply a timeout where the service call never returns. Sometimes a fresh deployment of my lambda function doesn't succeed for the 'first' call either.

I've tried exploring any [rate limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html) etc for STS but don't see any that are relevant. I can call `AssumeRole` from the CLI as many times as a I want and it's fast and responsive.

My Lambda function runs inside a VPC, and I've tried with and without an endpoint to STS (apparently you do not need an STS endpoint inside your VPC, which makes some sense).

So in summary - is there any extra intelligence happening during the `AssumeRole` operation which is causing this problem? Is something special or difference happening in the Lambda container that causes this to break? Any debugging ideas?

Comment: Why do you think you don't need an endpoint to STS? If your lambda does not have internet access, how it can connect to STS service?

Comment: I assumed I did need an endpoint, but it seems to work (sometimes) without. It makes some sense to me because all AWS services need STS access at some level, e.g. bootstrapping the lambda function always generates tokens under the covers.

Comment: When you "first deploy my Lambda function", does it work from withing VPC? Or rather it works outside of VPC at first, and then when you put it in a VPC it works for some time, and then stops?

Comment: @Marcin I've never run this outside a VPC, and it has succeeded from within the VPC. I'm exploring whether the endpoint makes any difference by deleting and testing then re-adding. I've updated the question as it doesn't *always* work when I first deploy it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure STS endpoint will be needed. But nevertheless, if you find otherwise, I would love to know how did your testing went and what are the conculusions. I also assume your lambda has no internet access through NAT gateway?

Comment: *"but eventually stops"*  What does this actually mean?  It doesn't just stop.  There must be some kind of error occurring, which you have not actually described.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot just a timeout - I've edited the question.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you've provisioned the Lambda function to run in two subnets that aren't identical.  One subnet has (a) a NAT Gateway as its default route and/or (b) access to an STS endpoint... and the other one has neither of these.  You can't get to STS without one or the other.